# OpenGL or DirectX equivalent

Tags: c#

I am looking into opengl and directx and was wondering what is the easiest to learn and which is the best in terms of community activity.

I also would like to know if openTK and tao are dead or not.

Any other advice or tutorials etc are welcome!

Comment: OpenTK is alive at the moment of writting. On the other hand Tao isn't... as far as I know. Easier to learn? I can't tell for sure because I never did really learn DirectX, the fact that OpenGL runs on more platforms is enough for me. I guess you could learn whathever you want if you put dedication to it.

Comment: So OpenTK is still alive? In that case I will sue that! Any tutorials or help or even a place to start that you would recommend?

Comment: Ever tried XNA? It's the 'official' managed way to develop games in Windows, Xbox and Windows Phone. But MS stopped the development yesterday, so... yeah. I'll still take it for the fact I can just develop graphic apps without leaving C# at all

Answer (score 2):

Whatever 3D application you are doing, if in the future you want to port to any platform other than Windows, you are better using OpenGL to begin with.

As for easier to learn, modern DirectX has an API that may result more familiar to people with experience with Microsoft tools. Also they provide good [documentations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh452744.aspx) and [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I recommend you [Coding4Fun](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/) to start with. Sorry I don't provide more, it is hard for me to decide if a DirectX tutorial is good as I don't know much of DirectX.

Also, you may be interested in [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) it will give you a good API for 2D application with hardware acceleration, or you can use it to initilize OpenGL both on Linux and Windows.

If you want to develop games, you may also consider some game engines, such as [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/), [Axiom](https://axiom.codeplex.com/) or even [Unity3D](http://www.unity3d.com/). You have already been told about [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx), so you owe a visit to [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/).

As for learning OpenGL, I did learn the old API the old way (With [The Red Book](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/)). You can also try [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) tutorials, and [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) has a [little tutorial](http://www.opentk.com/doc) and examples too.

Now, listen! OpenGL is the same, all that changes are a few details... for example some wrappers has prefixes on the function names, some use overloaded methods others stick the original OpenGL names... but it is the same, so you could easily adapt tutorials for C++, Java, JavaScript or whatever into C# when it comes to OpenGL, all that matters to learn to initialize it, setup some some events (Paint, Resize...) and all the rendering and stuff is the same...

So, knowing that, there are many, many more tutorials available for you. Here are a few:

- [OpenGL tutorial at codersource.net](http://www.codersource.net/mfc/opengl.aspx)
- [OpenGL Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming) at Wikibooks.org!
- The book [Learning Modern 3D Graphic Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/).
- Talking about books, [OpenGLBook](http://openglbook.com/the-book/)
- [Joe Greoff's Blog](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html)
- [Jefff LaMarche's Blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html)

Also, why not let the [Getting Started](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides) guide from [opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/) guide you?

Also, if what you want is examples. Take a look at [g-truc.net](http://www.g-truc.net/project-0026.html) and look no further... but I warn you, they have lots of code to read and digest.

And finally, for me the best way to learn to develop 3D applications is with a pet project. How about this: start with the classing technicolor triangle hello world tutorial, move on to drawing some cubes, afterward interface with it, make them move and rotate. Then move on to make a skybox, add a landscape and first person camara control... and finally your own 3D enviroment to navigate.